# C Semaphore Thread read file

Tags: c, multithreading, file, semaphore

I writing code where i have three threads that read lines from a file, and 3 three threads what write to the file. When the lines are read they are stored inside a buffer. when reading is completed would be activated. I have had a go at this and i'm able to make it work only with one thread for reading and one for thread for writing. At the moment i am pretty lost. 
Any help would be great.

Here are the fragments of code which i have written.

```
void *read_file(void *arg)
{
   semaphore_down(&sem_write);

   while(fgets(temp, MAX_BUFFER, file) != NULL)
   {    
    if(!isFull(&b))
    {
        printf("ADDING\n");
        read(&b,temp);
    }

}

    semaphore_up(&sem_read);
}       

void *write_file(void *arg)
{

    semaphore_down(&sem_read);
while(!isEmpty(&b))
{
    write(&b,&temp2);
    fprintf(file2, "%s", temp2);
}
semaphore_up(&sem_write);
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What are: `b`, `semaphore_down`, `semaphore_up`, `isFull`, `isEmpty`, `temp` and `temp2`, `file`, `file2`? You're not the only one who is lost.

Comment: b is the buffer, isFull is the buffer full. isEmpty, is buffer Empty. file is the input file.

Comment: I meant, what types are they and how and where are they defined and used? Simply, the fragments that you have posted are too incomplete and lack sufficient context to allow anyone to give you much help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all many things are not clear here such as definitions of various parameters, and flags.

From what I can udnerstand from your 2 functions, You have multiple Producers/Consumers problem. For multiple consumers i.e. readers it makes sense to have a semaphore. But while writting, it makes more sense to have a mutex for serializing the producers threads.

If you let multiple producer threads write into the same file, the file will be garbled.